# Excel VBA - Conditional highlighting - highlight next highest value

Tags: vba, excel

I have code that takes 3 pairs of values, highlights the highest (or lowest values) and then is supposed to highlight the next highest (or lowest value), to provide a second round of 2 pairs to match up.

While the code for highlighting the winner or the first 3 pairs could be a little cleaner (I went with above average, but maybe there is a way to just have it pick the highest value as opposed to the logic of above and below averages...), I cannot get the second part to work.  I went with the logic of formulating a top 10, which would provide me with that 4th value.  I don't get any error, and when I debug and try to print a value, I get nothing at all.

```
'Highlight winners of first round
    Range("C4:C6").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddAboveAverage
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).AboveBelow = xlAboveAverage
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 5296274
    Range("C9:C11").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddAboveAverage
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).AboveBelow = xlAboveAverage
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 5296274
    Range("C14:C16").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddAboveAverage
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).AboveBelow = xlAboveAverage
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 5296274

'Highlight highest losing analyst
    Range("C4:C16").Select
    If Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color <> 5296274 Then
        Selection.FormatConditions.AddTop10
        With Selection.FormatConditions
            .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
            .Rank = 10
        End With
        With Selection.FormatConditions.Interior
            .Color = 10092492
        End With
    End If
```

[image]

Any ideas on my issue?

Edited: A screenshot was added to show what the file looks like after the script runs.  The winner of each matchup is shown, however, since the next round would also be head to head, I need the "4th" place person to be highlighted as well, in this case, person  B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you'd be able to do what you're trying strictly with only conditional formatting.  I'd steer clear of them in this instance and just use regular vba.  Set 'rng' in this sub to the 1st cell of each set of times.  As per our discussion the lowest values are the winner for each pair.  Each loser's value is then checked to see whether it's the lower than the lowest value seen thus far; if it is then the 'minval' variable is updated with this value and the pointer to that cell, 'mincell', is also updated.

```
Sub OrgHighestAndNext1()

    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = [C4,C9,C14]

    Range("C" & rng.Row & ":C" & rng.Areas(3).Rows.Row + 2).Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

    Dim cell As Range, scell As Range, mincell As Range
    Dim minval As Double: minval = 9999.9

    For Each cell In rng
      If cell.Value2 < cell.Offset(2, 0).Value2 Then
         cell.Interior.Color = 5296274
         Set scell = cell.Offset(2, 0).Cells
      Else
         cell.Offset(2, 0).Interior.Color = 5296274
         Set scell = cell.Cells
      End If

      If scell.Value2 < minval Then
        Set mincell = scell
        minval = scell.Value2
      End If
    Next

    mincell.Interior.Color = 10092492
End Sub
```

Winners (lowest) value are given a background of dark green.  Loser background is left unchanged (white if worksheet was that way to begin with).  The lowest of the loser (what 'mincell' points to after all pairs have been processed) is given a color of light green.

Speaking in terms of ranking based only on time from lowest to
highest the seeds are ranked like this: 2,3,5,6,4,1 so seed 6 is the
4th ranked purely on time alone.  But if you rank first based on
winners times and then losers times the seeds are ranked like this:
2,3,6 (these are winners) and 5,4,1 (losers).   What you're after is
this second type of ranking - in which you really don't care about
the winners but do want the losers ranked according to lowest time so
you can find the loser with the best (lowest) time.

Comment: Yes I apologize, I should clear it up more.  There are two values separated by a blank cell, hence the range of 3 cells.  So that I understand yours correctly, what my goal is is to highlight the "winner" of each match up, and then highlight the "best loser" (IE the 4th seed) in a separate color

Comment: how do I switch it so that the code can also work where the "winning" values are the smallest?  If I change the first greater than to a less than, I get the 3 lowest values, but if I switch the second greater than to a less than, I get an "Object variable not set" error on the maxcell.interior.color line.  If I change the maxcell to mincell (and also declare it) it does not work.  What am I missing?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're after. If you switch the 1st greater than sign, you'll highlight all the losers of each round.  With that change and to get the winner with the lowest time, you'd have to set maxval to something like 999.9 initially and then change the second greater than to a less than sign.

Comment: In this example, the lower numbers are actually winners, not higher.  So 1, 2 and 3 would win out versus 4, 5 and 6, and 4 would be the "best loser".  Switching the first sign gives me the lower winners, but it was that 4th winner I could not get

Comment: Okay lower # is the winner - makes sense.  So what you're showing in your picture is that the winner of each round has a white background (losers have a dark green background).  You want the 4th placed person based on a sorted ranking from lowest to highest highlighted with a light green background?  If you can confirm, I can revise the code to get you that.  So as per your original problem statement you want 0:05:15 shown highlighted in light green?

Comment: Yes, so basically I have 7 different categories.  Some are times, some are whole number values, some are percentages.  Four of the categories, the higher values are better, and the other 3, lower are better.  So in my example, lower is actually the better value.  I just kept it at higher since I needed that code to work as well (albeit it for a different category).  In the above example, seed 6, 2 and 3 should win, with seed 5 as the 4th placed person.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That did it.  Thanks!